# vim -N mode: where to use it?

Tags: vim

I am following the Peepcode screencasts to learn vim.

The presenter mentions about the `-N` mode but doesn't elaborate it much and says that it should be the default mode.

My questions:

- What is the `-N` mode?
- Should I always use it?
- If yes, how do I configure it in the `.vimrc`?

EDIT: The author does mention that it should always be used, but doesn't elaborate why and how.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running `vim -N` sets Vim in "nocompatible" mode, which drops strict backwards compatibility with the original `vi` in favor of better features.  Unless you know that you need (or want) backwards compatibility, it's better to go with the features.

If you have a `.vimrc` file in the first place, Vim will by default put you in nocompatible mode, but the command `set nocompatible` will seal the deal.

See the following Vim help topics for more info:

```
:help compatible
:help compatible-default
```

Comment: Does it matter when I am learning??

Comment: I'd definitely set nocompatible, for the unlimited undo feature if nothing else.  In original `vi`, pressing the "u" key twice is the same as not pressing it at all, whereas in Vim, `u` and `Ctrl-r` are your multi-level undo and redo.

Answer (score 0):

load VIM without .vimrc and plugins (clean VIM) e.g. for HUGE files so it loads quicker . Another reason is when you might have a bad config or unwanted plugin or clashing features or you fear you've overloaded a vim command

```
gvim -u NONE -U NONE -N hugedatabase.sql
```